# Change intercept using lmer function in R

Tags: r, intercept, lmer

I am trying to use the lmer function to investigate if there is an interaction effect on the reaction time (RT) between 3 different conditions (cond=0, 1, 2) and the presence of the target (target=False or True) in patients (Patient).

I wrote the following equation:

```
lmer(RT~cond*target+(1|Patient))
```

My problem is that the default intercept for this function is cond = 0 and target = False, whereas I would like the intercept to be cond= 0 and target=True (in order to see if there is a significant difference between cond0*target=True and cond1*target=True).

I would really appreciate your help.

Here is the output I have

```
stu3<-lmer(RT~cond*target+(1|Patient), 
   data=subset(ss, Groupe=="ugs" & primeable ==TRUE     & 
          Correct==TRUE & NoPrac==TRUE))

pvals.fnc(stu3)


$fixed
                  Estimate MCMCmean HPD95lower HPD95upper  pMCMC Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)         0.5511   0.5513     0.5258     0.5807 0.0001   0.0000
cond1               0.0618   0.0619     0.0498     0.0741 0.0001   0.0000
cond2               0.0285   0.0285     0.0142     0.0438 0.0002   0.0001
targetFALSE         0.1389   0.1389     0.1239     0.1549 0.0001   0.0000
cond1:targetFALSE  -0.0752  -0.0751    -0.0943    -0.0545 0.0001   0.0000
cond2:targetFALSE  -0.0788  -0.0786    -0.0998    -0.0564 0.0001   0.0000

$random
    Groups        Name Std.Dev. MCMCmedian MCMCmean HPD95lower HPD95upper
1  Patient (Intercept)   0.0610     0.0583   0.0599     0.0425     0.0797
2 Residual               0.1674     0.1674   0.1674     0.1650     0.1699
```

Based on my data, the intercept being chosen is `cond0:targetTRUE` and the other levels in the output are `cond1:targetFALSE` and `cond2:targetFALSE`.

Comment: so the `cond1` parameter should exactly correspond to a test of the difference between `cond==0` and `cond==1` when `target` is `TRUE` (provided that you haven't done anything else clever with your contrasts ...), which is what it sounds like you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

See if standard "factor management" is effective:

```
target=factor(target, levels=c("TRUE", "FALSE")
lmer(RT~cond*target+(1|Patient))
```

(I would have used the phrase "changing the reference levels" rather than "changing the intercept", but I suppose it's really the same process. I suspect the phrase "[r] change reference level" would have gotten you quite few hits on a Google or SO search.)

Comment: and be careful with exact matches of the levels -- i.e. are your factor levels `TRUE` and `FALSE`, or `"True"` and `"False"`, or `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"` ... ?

Comment: I constructed my advice on the assumption that 'target' was a logical vector, In which case they would have been as written, but if they were factors spelled as Ben fears (and as you wrote) then do follow his advice and make sure they match the spelling. It's always best to provide str() on your data elements.

Comment: The factor levels are TRUE and FALSE Ben. I tried to follow your advice DWin but it only switches things around: this time the intercept is the interaction cond0*targetTrue but it compares it to cond1*targetFalse.

Comment: I suspect you don't understand what the output means. The coefficients in a model with interactions are NOT comparisons.

Comment: I might not have expressed myself well, sorry. But the problem still holds, I need the interactions in the levels to be the same as the level of reference in order to evaluate if there is a significant difference between the conditions and the presence of the target. But thank you for clarifying my phrasing mistake Dwin.

Comment: I think we need to see full output and I also wonder if this might be better conducted on CrossValidated because I am still of the opinion that we no longer have coding issues to resolve but rather conceptual ones.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, your model is already doing the interpretation you would wish to have inside `target==TRUE`. If I am correct, you could translate the model terms in your example as follows:

```
"(Intercept)"       -> target==TRUE, cond==0 (even if model matrix contains all conds)
"cond1"             -> target==TRUE, cond==1 on top of cond==0
"cond2"             -> target==TRUE, cond==2 on top of cond==0
"targetFALSE"       -> target==FALSE, cond==0 (even if model matrix contains all conds)
"cond1:targetFALSE" -> target==FALSE, cond==1 on top of cond==0
"cond2:targetFALSE" -> target==FALSE, cond==2 on top of cond==0
```

So isn't the interesting difference detected in terms `"(Intercept)"`, `"cond1"` and `"cond2"`? Taking a look at the fixed effects' model matrix structure in `getME(stu3,'X')` may be helpful.

Below is an example data I constructed to test your case. Notice that I built three different responses: one without any effect, one with just `target==TRUE` effect, and one with an effect for `target==TRUE` and an interaction effect with `target==TRUE` and the different levels of `cond`. The artificially introduced effect is detected in `fit1` and `fit2`:

```
set.seed(0)
struct <- expand.grid(target = c(FALSE,TRUE), cond = as.factor(0:2), patient = LETTERS[1:20])
attach(struct)
ranpatient <- rep(rnorm(20), each=6)
rerror <- rnorm(120)
# Just random noise
response0 <- ranpatient + rerror
# When target==TRUE we increment the response by 1 and add errors
response1 <- 1*target + ranpatient + rerror
# When target==TRUE we increment the response by  1,
# to which we also add an interaction effect condition {0,1,2} * target {0,1}
# notice that numeric transformation of cond {0,1,2} transforms to ranks {1,2,3}
response2 <- 1*target + target*(as.numeric(cond)-1) + ranpatient + rerror

dat <- data.frame(cond, target, patient, response0, response1, response2)   
detach(struct)

require(lme4)
fit0 <- lmer(response0 ~ cond*target + (1|patient), data=dat)
fit1 <- lmer(response1 ~ cond*target + (1|patient), data=dat)
fit2 <- lmer(response2 ~ cond*target + (1|patient), data=dat)

head(dat)
round(coef(summary(fit0)),2) # Notice low t values
round(coef(summary(fit1)),2) # High t value for targetTRUE
round(coef(summary(fit2)),2) # High t value for interaction cond0/1/2 with targetTRUE
# Notice how cond==1 adds 1, and cond==2 adds 2 in comparison to cond==0 when targetTRUE
# Notice also that coefficient "cond2:targetTRUE" is incremental to term "targetTRUE", not "cond1:targetTRUE"
head(getME(fit2,'X')) # Columns correspond to the fixed effect terms
```

With the output

```
> head(dat)
  cond target patient response0 response1 response2
1    0  FALSE       A  1.038686  1.038686  1.038686
2    0   TRUE       A  1.640350  2.640350  2.640350
3    1  FALSE       A  1.396291  1.396291  1.396291
4    1   TRUE       A  2.067144  3.067144  4.067144
5    2  FALSE       A  1.205848  1.205848  1.205848
6    2   TRUE       A  1.766562  2.766562  4.766562
> round(coef(summary(fit0)),2) # Notice low t values
                 Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)         -0.13       0.31   -0.40
cond1                0.18       0.29    0.62
cond2                0.00       0.29    0.00
targetTRUE           0.00       0.29   -0.01
cond1:targetTRUE     0.13       0.41    0.32
cond2:targetTRUE     0.08       0.41    0.19
> round(coef(summary(fit1)),2) # High t value for targetTRUE
                 Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)         -0.13       0.31   -0.40
cond1                0.18       0.29    0.62
cond2                0.00       0.29    0.00
targetTRUE           1.00       0.29    3.42
cond1:targetTRUE     0.13       0.41    0.32
cond2:targetTRUE     0.08       0.41    0.19
> round(coef(summary(fit2)),2) # High t value for interaction cond0/1/2 with targetTRUE
                 Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)         -0.13       0.31   -0.40
cond1                0.18       0.29    0.62
cond2                0.00       0.29    0.00
targetTRUE           1.00       0.29    3.42
cond1:targetTRUE     1.13       0.41    2.75
cond2:targetTRUE     2.08       0.41    5.04
> # Notice how cond==1 adds 1, and cond==2 adds 2 in comparison to cond==0 when targetTRUE
> # Notice also that coefficient "cond2:targetTRUE" is incremental to term "targetTRUE", not "cond1:targetTRUE"
> head(getME(fit2,'X')) # Columns correspond to the fixed effect terms
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    1    0    0
[3,]    1    1    0    0    0    0
[4,]    1    1    0    1    1    0
[5,]    1    0    1    0    0    0
[6,]    1    0    1    1    0    1
```

Comment: this all makes sense to me.  The only adjustment I would ask is to use the accessor methods: `coef(summary())` rather than `@coefs` and `getME(.,"X")` rather than `@X`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll keep it in mind. I now corrected the above code and output.